# Would like to be able to vote on electing moderators when I see their actions

Tags: feature-request, moderator-election, moderators

I don't vote on Moderator elections--I generally don't remember the names of moderators that I've seen do things I appreciated or disliked, I'd have to be taking daily notes.

I just realized I'd really love to be able to vote for/against moderators early (perhaps up/down on their user page or a page with their moderation philosophy--just a +/- like when we vote for a question), one user gets one vote per moderator per election.

It would be fine if it would just remember my vote until the election and proxy-vote for me then, I'm not asking for a procedural change just some help in remembering who I want to vote for in the next election.

Comment: *just some help in remembering who I want to vote for in the next election* - write a post it?

Comment: Make a section in your profile: "Inspirational Actions"

Comment: How do you know who is going to nominate themselves in the next election? How does this “user voting” then turn into a _ranking_ that you still have to do in the election? What if all candidates are “voted” positively? Or negatively? What if a user is voted negatively and nominates themselves years later — isn’t it likely that they changed their behavior in the meantime?

Comment: This... seems like a way to really do the worst job that you can do when doing an election. It is probably better to just not participate in the election process at all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no practical way to register your vote before an election. This is because you don't vote "for" or "against" candidates: you rank them, and then your vote is [transferred according to an algorithm](https://blog.opavote.com/2017/04/meek-stv-explained.html?m=1) as needed.

In any case, there are just too many people who could run for moderator. Looking on meta (with its drastically shorter list of active users), there are about 50 pages of users who have enough reputation to run. Likely less than ten will run in the next election. Considering the size of Stack Overflow, it's entirely possible that you won't have run into any of the candidates on the main site, and may not even recognize everyone even if you're active on Meta. If you tried to evaluate users before you knew who's running, it's very likely you wasted a lot of time evaluating people who didn't run.

The only way to vote fairly is to see the list of nominees and look into their backgrounds.